# How to access the Fabric (Twitter) plugin in Intellij 13?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13, intellij-plugin, twitter-fabric

I have just installed the [Fabric (Twitter) plugin](https://fabric.io/) in IntelliJ IDEA 13, following [the steps found here](https://fabric.io/downloads/intellij).

I installed the plugin, restarted IntelliJ and the next step suggested by the guide is this:

[image]

However, I couldn't find that button anywhere, not even in the menus on the top. The plugin shows up as installed in Settings -> Plugins.

**How can I access the Fabric plugin after installation in IntelliJ IDEA?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please enable View -> Toolbar and you can see.

Comment: That's the solution their support team suggested as well. Hopefully they'll mention it in the steps. Thanks!